# Sandcastle & SHFB, hide fields from TOC?

Tags: sandcastle, tableofcontents, shfb

I'm currently documenting a WCF service and need to strip the TOC to a bare minimum. Is it possible to exclude fields sub topic from a class' TOC?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer on SHFB dicussion group: http://shfb.codeplex.com/discussions/360799#post853302

Answer (score 0):

There is now a plugin for that:
[Table of Contents Exclusion Plug-In](http://ewsoftware.github.io/SHFB/html/d0e91b66-135e-446b-9239-c02fcafabd09.htm)